# Implementing Linear probing Java

Tags: java, hashcode

I am trying to implement the linear probing method. Right now, I have come until this point:

```
public class LinearProbing<Key, Value> {
private int size = 300001;
private Value[] value = (Value[]) new Object[size];
private Key[] key = (Key[]) new Object[size];

public Value put(Key thiskey, Value thisval) {
    int hash = thiskey.hashCode();
    for (int i = hash; key[i] != null; i = (i + 1) % size) {
        if(key[i] == hash)
        break;
        key[i] = thiskey;
        value[i] = thisval;
    }
}
}
```

I am bit confused to proceed after this. Here are my doubts:

1. When I check the equality of this.key == hash, I get an error saying I can't compare Key and int.So I decided to return the Object from the hashcode method and compare it with the this.key[i].equals(hashObject). However doing this is against as hashcode method returns the int in the Javadoc and I want to keep it that way. How do I solve this?

Please let me know if I wasn't clear.

Comment: You can't use == to compare objects in Java, as == is based on whether the references are effectively the same pointer. == does not do content comparison; you need to use `if(key[i].equals(hash))`, although since `key[i]` is a `Key`, and `hash` is an int, that still won't work.

Comment: Yes! Right. I just tried the equals! :)

Comment: I am thinking of using an Integer so that I can use the equals. Am I correct by doing so? I'm trying on the side too.

Comment: Integer hash = thiskey.hashCode();
And then I am trying key[i].equals(hash). Is this right?

Comment: no, you're still comparing two things that have no intuitive comparison. A `Key` object cannot ever be equal to a primitive `int` data type, so instead you'll want to give the `Key` class a method like `int getHash() { return this.hash; }`, and then do the comparison as a true == check with `if(key[i].getHash() == hash) { ... } `

Comment: Aha! Nice. Will work on that!